Error deploying a specific Firebase cloud function - Provided module can't be loaded
I have deployed this function before with no issues and I have not changed the code apart from adding the code:
.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540, memory: "1GB"} )

as it had timed out and had an error. Now I just get the error below when deploying.

I have deleted the function in production as it says "failed to deploy" and I am trying to redeploy it.
I am not using the crypto module, I tried npm i crypto with no change
Deploying a new test function has the same error.
I have contacted support and waiting on response

Error:
 Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
 Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?

        Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'node:crypto'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
            at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
            at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/uuid/dist/rng.js:7:42)
            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
            at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
            at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
            at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/uuid/dist/v1.js:7:35)
            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
            at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
            at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
            at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/uuid/dist/index.js:94:33)
            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

This is the function. I have simplified it and I am still getting the error. I also get the error deploying the function with a different name.
export const stripeCancelAllSubscriptions = functions
  .region('region-commented-out')
  .https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
  // Commented out core logic for testing
  return { message: 'Function deployed successfully' };
});

This is the test function that has the same error:
export const debugFunction = functions
.region('us-east1')
.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
  return { message: 'Function deployed successfully' };
});

Other:
1st gen functions
 "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
"firebase-functions": "^3.24.1",

Node 16.20.0 installed locally
Update
I temporarily fixed it by removing
const { google } = require('googleapis'); 

and all code that used googleapis just for the deployment of the one function I needed. So it looks like it is connected to this. I guess I need to delete the package-lock.json and try and reinstall everything?

Yes I would start by deleting package.lock.json and reinstalling. Another suggestion that might help indirectly: note googleapis is a HUGE library. You should only import the subpackage that you actually need, like npm install @googleapis/bigquery  then const bigquery = require('@googleapis/bigquery').  Maybe that will leave the underlying problem out of your code.

Thanks @maganap that suggestion makes a lot of sense as I only need two sub-packages. Having some trouble with the first sub-package here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78690453/how-to-create-an-oauth2client-using-the-googleapis-oauth2-subpackage

I couldn't get the auth2 subpackage to work but I managed to get it working using the entire package.

Solved by

Deleting node_modules folder
Deleting package.lock.json
Migrating from node 10 to node 18 for firebase cloud functions
Updating the @types/node package to 18
Updating typescript to 4.8.4
Updating googelapis from 134.0.0 to 140.0.1
running npm install

Not sure if all of those were necessary.
