How to create an oAuth2Client using the @googleapis/oauth2 subpackage
I am trying to move from using the entire googleapis package in my firebase cloud function (nodejs) project to using only the sub packages I need.
This is what I have that works currently:
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URI
);

oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });
// Do some stuff with oAuth2Client

This is what I am trying to do but not having success. I have run npm i @googleapis/oauth2.
I am getting

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to
generate manifest from function source: TypeError: OAuth2 is not a
constructor

const { OAuth2 } = require('@googleapis/oauth2');
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2 (
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URI
);

oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });
// Do some stuff with oAuth2Client

I have also tried new OAuth2.auth.OAuth2(1) and OAuth2.OAuth2(2) and get:
(1)

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to
generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read
properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

(2)

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to
generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read
properties of undefined (reading 'OAuth2')


Been there. I ended up with this:
import * as googleAuth from 'google-auth-library';


async function getOAuthClient(secrets, { credentials } = {}) {
  const { clientId, clientSecret, serverRedirectUri } = secrets;
  const clientOptions = { clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri: serverRedirectUri };

  const oauth2Client = new googleAuth.OAuth2Client(clientOptions);

  if (credentials) {
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(credentials);
  }

  return oauth2Client;
}

These below as an example:
async function generateAuthUrl() {
  const secrets = await getSecrets();
  const oauth2Client = await getOAuthClient(secrets);

  const authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    include_granted_scopes: true,
    scope: scopes,
  });

  return { authorizeUrl };
}

async function authConfirmation(code) {
  const secrets = await getSecrets();
  const oauth2Client = await getOAuthClient(secrets);

  const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
  await setTokens(tokens);

  return { redirectUrl: secrets.clientRedirectUri };
}

// scopes in my case is:
const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage',
];
// since I'm using
// import { mybusinessaccountmanagement } from '@googleapis/mybusinessaccountmanagement';

I have this at the top of my readme file, after hours of struggling, maybe they're of help to you:

"googleapis": "^133.0.0" (for node), also works, but too heavy library
"@googleapis/mybusinessaccountmanagement" more lightweight

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client?tab=readme-ov-file#oauth2-client
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2700
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/samples/oauth2.js
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list#authorization-scopes
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/implement-oauth
